# How can I increase the width of range cutout in a granite countertop?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, range

The builders of my house did some strange things. One of those strange things was providing a 29 7/8 inch (759 mm) cutout for the range. The standard cutout size is 30 inches (762 mm), and the standard width for a range is 29 7/8 inches. It’s an extremely tight fit for our existing range.

Now our range is broken and we need to buy a new one. However, appliance companies won’t even try to install a new range unless we have a standard 30 inch cutout.

I need to remove 1/8 inch (about 3 mm) of granite countertop and wood face trim from one side of the cutout. I figure the wood trim is an easy job for an oscillating multi tool, but I don’t know the best way to remove that tiny sliver of granite. Any suggestions?

Comment: The builder didn't do "strange things". They merely had a 1/8" error. It happens when you're dealing with wood, gypsum, and stone provided by multiple crews. It wasn't intentional. Carpentry can be challenging.

Comment: Why do you need an appliance _installed_? They usually just plug in, or maybe have a simple gas connection. D it Y it and forget about carving stone. Chances are it'll fit. Most appliances are undersized _at least_ 1/8".

Comment: Is this actually granite, or a synthetic? Wood on granite is not common.

Comment: @isherwood "Wood on granite is not common"? I don't understand this comment, I see granite on top of wood cabinetry all the time. What else would be used? OP was talking about the face trim, which I assume to be the vertical wood pieces on either side of the range.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted "wood face trim". That could indeed be the cabinet faceframe. I had interpreted it as a countertop edge, as is common with laminate tops. My question stands.

Comment: When I got a replacement KitchenAid gas cooktop - replacing the equivalent previous model (same brand/type), I found that it needed a slightly larger cutout. I could have done it myself but I don't DIY gas (I have my limits) so when my plumber (licensed for gas) came in to do the job, I told him to take care of it. He was reluctant "it won't look good, blah blah blah) but I knew he was a perfectionist and also that the lip of the cooktop would cover any reasonable jagged edge - and it all ended up just fine.

Comment: How far can you get by not telling the appliance delivery guys that your cutout is not any different from 30"?  I don't imagine they're going to measure. There might be just enough room to get it in there without any issues.

Comment: Let's hope that the cabinet face frames are at least 30" apart too, or *they'll* need to be clearanced as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers are good, but I did this job recently, so can provide a bit of additional perspective.

First, take a tape measure to the appliance showroom and see if you can get something slightly undersized. The brand you had might be the first try. If you can’t find the right size and you’re determined to diy, try to find one with a lip on the side that overlaps the countertop — that’ll hide minor sins/chips.

If the showroom doesn’t help with a narrower unit, I strongly suggest a pro. They have the tools and the experience to tackle this. Whatever they charge is insurance that you won’t have to replace all your counters because you broke something.

While I’m a professional, this task is quite a ways out of my wheelhouse, so I wasn’t pleased when I got assigned to it. Spoiler: it worked out fine, but there was the possibility that we’d be replacing an entire kitchen worth of granite.

Dust is a huge concern, and needs to be managed. I built a floor to ceiling dust tent and used an industrial air scrubber that was vented to the outside to create negative pressure. Every cabinet and counter surface was draped with plastic, even outside the tent. Every drawer and door was taped along the edges.

Cutting was with a 7-1/4 diamond blade in an old circular saw. Old because the dust is terrible for tools. Countertop pros might be set up to wet cut which is probably better.

I set up a 1x4 fence on the counter to guide the shoe of the saw and ensure a straight line. I used double sided tape, though I’d use hot glue if I had to do it again. I cut in one pass, really really slowly. You might do multiple passes at increasing depth, but you’d have to be sure that the fence doesn’t squirm.

The saw won’t cut all the way to the wall, so I had to use a grinder with a diamond blade and be careful.

I used a diamond grit cutter in the oscillating tool to knock down the sharp top edge.

All told, it was an experience; one I’ve vowed never to repeat.

Answer (score 3):

Router bits for granite are made - they'll be diamond abrasive tooling. You can also get diamond blades for an angle grinder or circular saw.

Best bet for decent appearance is probably to hire a stone countertop contractor who will have the right tools (which you can buy if you really want to) and experience (which you'll be picking up on the job, and it's likely to show.)

Comment: With having to compare the shaved/cut edge of the counter to the perfect straight edge of the range, you kind of want the shaved/cut edge perfect also.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't indicate what tools you own, but the best way and the way cabinet/counter pros would do this, is with a grinder and diamond blade.

You can rent a grinder. If you don't have one also rent a shop vac. This will be dusty. Use a 
[wet/ dry diamond blade](https://www.parts-express.com/Arlington-CS7-Plastic-Cable-Standoff-261-4268?quantity=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=19344435533&utm_content=144470248733&gadid=642323859525&gclid=CjwKCAjwp6CkBhB_EiwAlQVyxaHPX6g5UTqnqLawcnEigg14L_3h7Nof_db3yvOg9G1PvQvprHi-ZRoCd7YQAvD_BwE). Have someone hold the vac hose close to the edge of the counter and use the grinder with the blade parallel to the counter edge.

Start at the back and press the blade into the counter while pulling it toward the front.  This is more like scraping or sanding off the edge than cutting through it. It may take a few passes but you will get it shaved down quicker than you think.

Use a tape on the top of the counter to mark the edge of the 1/8 you want to take off. Measure after each pass. It is easy to shave too much.

Then have the celebratory drink of your choice....you will have a lot of clean up.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look out for the difference between a "drop-in" range and a standalone.   The former is designed to sit on top of the countertop so there is no visible gap.  The body will not have sides.   A standalone range will slide in and you have to deal with the fit.